# Difference between Attach and FromImage under storage_os_disk when using "azurerm_virtual_machine" resource in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I was using terraform to spin up my azure resources. But what I can't seem to understand is, what is the difference between Attach and FromImage under "storage_os_disk" when using "azurerm_virtual_machine" resource. I am assuming Attach would be referring to a disk already provisioned. Can you please help me in understanding the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `Attach` means you can attach an existing disk when you are using a specialized disk to create the VM. The `FromImage` means you can create a disk in the virtual machine from a platform or user image.

You could refer to `DiskCreateOptionTypes` API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get#diskcreateoptiontypes).
[image]